# Why different behavior of Single when using just or fromCallable in startWith?

Tags: rx-java2

I'm starting a `PublishSubject` with `testPublishSubject.startWith(createSingle().toObservable())`.

If I subscribe to this observable, dispose and subscribe again, it will emit a different item depending on how I created the `Single`. If I create it with `just`, it emits the same item as the first time (`item1`), if I create it with `fromCallable`, it emits the updated item (`item2`). Why is the behavior different? Is there a way to use `just` and have it behave like `fromCallable`?

**Edit:** Ok, I think I know why it behaves differently. It's because it's not re-creating the `Single`. `fromCallable` works only because of the closure, which is executed again with the updated counter.

My updated question would be: Is there a way to have the subject re-create the `Single`? The reason I want this, is because the Single is fetching a value, which may have been updated, and I need to fetch it again.

```
var counter = 1

// With this, it works as expected
//    fun createSingle(): Single<String> = Single.fromCallable {
//        "item-${counter++}"
//    }
// With this, the second subscription still shows "item-1
fun createSingle(): Single<String> = Single.just("item-${counter++}")

val testPublishSubject = PublishSubject.create<String>()
val observable = testPublishSubject.startWith(createSingle().toObservable().doOnNext {
    log(">>> single on next: $it")
}).doOnNext {
    log(">>> publish subject on next: $it")
}

log(">>> subscribing1")
val disposable1 = observable.subscribe {
    log(">>> value subscription 1: $it")
}

log(">>> pushing random item")
testPublishSubject.onNext("random item")

log(">>> disposing subscription1")
disposable1.dispose()

log(">>> subscribing2")
val disposable2 = observable.subscribe {
    log(">>> value subscription 2: $it")
}
```

Comment: `just` takes a constant reference and emits it to subscribers. `fromCallable` executes a calculation every time it gets subscribed to thus the result could be different to different observers. Why don't you use `fromCallable`? Otherwise, use `defer(() -> createSingle().toObservable())`.

Comment: @akarnokd not sure how to use `defer` in this case. I fixed it by replacing `PublishSubject` with `BehaviorSubject`.